# Google chrome white screen on inspect element

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am facing a weird problem in my chrome browser and i searched all over net but couldn't find solution.

When ever i click **inspect element**, the webpage turns to a white screen. and to retreive back i need to go to fullscreen mode. Is that a bug in chrome?? or in my system???

I am using chrome `Version 35.0.1870.2 dev` and `Mac MountainLion`. kindly help me out

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: The version of Chrome you're using is really **outdated**. It was released in **2014**! You **must** update it. I'm not sure if the latest version supports MountainLion; Check this QA for some tips to update it https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237271/is-there-a-google-chrome-version-50-supporting-mac-os-10-8-5

Answer (score 4):

Try to update your google chrome. (run it as admin if needed)

Also for me, I do recommend you to use Mozilla Firefox Developer Edition as they have more Developer Tools

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your Google Chrome.

Also check if the issue is happening in [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/canary.html), which is early-release, experimental version of Chrome. If its working fine in Chrome Canary, it just means the issue will be fixed in coming versions of Chrome Stable.

Also as [Joshua Dela Cruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976244/joshua-dela-cruz) suggested, you can try [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), also called as Aurora.